# Laravel Validation Same not Working as intended

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm writing a Request Validator in `Laravel`, where I have the following conditions. To check if passwords given are the same, this will fail, with the message that the passwords are not the same, even though the passwords are the same.

```
'password1' => 'string',
'password2' => 'string|same: password1'
```

If I disable the validation and `dd(Input::only('password1','password2'));`, it will print out the following.

```
array:2 [
    "password1" => "123"
    "password2" => "123"
]
```

Why is the `same` validation not working?

Comment: Space between `same:` and `password1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is the space in your validation rule. You don't have a field named `[space]password1` in your input, so the validation fails. Instead of `same: password1`, it should be `same:password1`.

```
'password1' => 'string',
'password2' => 'string|same:password1'
```

---

Another way that password confirmation is usually done is with the `confirmed` validation. Typically you have a `password` field and a `password_confirmation` field, and then the `confirmed` validation will validate that your `password` input has matching input from a `*_confirmation` field.

```
'password' => 'string|confirmed',
'password_confirmation' => 'string',
```